# How to resize multiple WPF controls when the text size changes?

Tags: wpf

What's the correct pattern to resize controls when a font size changes?

For example, I used the WPF designer to make a form, and placed UI elements from the toolbox.  Late in the game I got the requirement that the font size of every UI element needs to be configurable, so now I'm thinking there has to be a better way to resize controls when the font size changes.  Right now I'm doing  alot of code behind calculations on Margin properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For such cases I usually place my control inside Grids and StackPanels, this way font size won't affect the layout, everything will be stretchable.

Never place controls on the Window using absolute coordinates.

Comment: +1 this Eugen is right this is the base design rule in WPF (or similar). Consider that even later on you might get requirement for localization of your GUI. `Grid`s, `DockPanel`s, `StackPanel`s and especially `WrapPanel`s will save you!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your Height and Width on the controls are set to Auto.
When you use the designer/toolbox to add controls it usually provides a static height/width.  If you type the tag in the XAML editor you get the control default which is usually Auto.

You'll notice the black diamond in the property window next to the attributes that are changed from their default value.  You can right click and choose **reset value** to clear the attribute from your XAML and see what the default value is.